# How do I replace missing/masked data with a row mean with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, missing-data

How would I replace the missing values in the 'b' array below with the corresponding row averages in 'c'?

```
a=numpy.arange(24).reshape(4,-1)
b=numpy.ma.masked_where(numpy.remainder(a,5)==0,a);b
Out[46]: 
 masked_array(data =
 [[-- 1 2 3 4 --]
 [6 7 8 9 -- 11]
 [12 13 14 -- 16 17]
 [18 19 -- 21 22 23]],
         mask =
 [[ True False False False False  True]
 [False False False False  True False]
 [False False False  True False False]
 [False False  True False False False]],
       fill_value = 999999)

c=b.mean(axis=1);c
Out[47]: 
masked_array(data = [2.5 8.2 14.4 20.6],
         mask = [False False False False],
   fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
np.copyto(b, c[...,None], where=b.mask)
```

You have to add the extra axis to `c` so that it knows to apply it to each row.  (if `np.mean` had a `keepdims` option like `np.sum`, this wouldn't be necessary :P

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(24).reshape(4,-1).astype(float)   # I changed your example to be a float
b = np.ma.masked_where(numpy.remainder(a,5)==0,a)
c = b.mean(1)

np.copyto(b, c[...,None], where=b.mask)

In [189]: b.data
Out[189]: 
array([[  2.5,   1. ,   2. ,   3. ,   4. ,   2.5],
       [  6. ,   7. ,   8. ,   9. ,   8.2,  11. ],
       [ 12. ,  13. ,  14. ,  14.4,  16. ,  17. ],
       [ 18. ,  19. ,  20.6,  21. ,  22. ,  23. ]])
```

This is faster than creating an `inds` array:

```py
In [169]: %%timeit
   .....: inds = np.where(b.mask)
   .....: b[inds] = np.take(c, inds[0])
   .....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 81.2 µs per loop


In [173]: %%timeit
   .....: np.copyto(b, c[...,None], where=b.mask)
   .....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 45.1 µs per loop
```

Another advantage is that it will warn you about the dtype issue:

```py
a = np.arange(24).reshape(4,-1)    # still an int
b = np.ma.masked_where(numpy.remainder(a,5)==0,a)
c = b.mean(1)

In [193]: np.copyto(b, c[...,None], where=b.mask)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-193-edc7f01f3f89> in <module>()
----> 1 np.copyto(b, c[...,None], where=b.mask)

TypeError: Can not cast scalar from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'same_kind'
```

---

By the way, there is a set of functions for such a task, depending on what different source formats you have, such as

[`np.put`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put.html)
sequentially puts the input array into the output array in locations given by indices and would work like @Ophion's answer.

[`np.place`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.place.html)
sequentially assigns each element from the input (list or 1d array) into places in the output array wherever the mask is true, (not aligned with the input array, as their shapes don't have to match).

[`np.copyto`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copyto.html)
will always put a value from the input array into the same (broadcasted) location in the output array. Shapes must match (or be broadcastable).  It effectively replaces the older function [`np.putmask`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.putmask.html).

Comment: Thats interesting that `copyto` will broadcast in that way.

Comment: I would be very hesitant to call this a family as each of these functions utilize different underlying C calls. `np.copyto` is new and very unique in the fact that it is the only one of these capable of broadcasting.

Comment: Fair enough, @Ophion. I hope "set" is ok :P  I was trying to connect them by their similar usage cases, and I wasn't hesitant because of the fact that they are all mutually linked in their doc pages.  You're right, `copyto` is the only one where broadcasting makes sense ... I tried to make clearer that `put` and `place` take from effectively a list and put/place all (well, N) elements from it, where copyto keeps them all aligned, hence the utility of broadcasting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `where` and `take`:

```
inds = np.where(b.mask)

b[inds] = np.take(c,inds[0])

b
masked_array(data =
 [[2 1 2 3 4 2]
 [6 7 8 9 8 11]
 [12 13 14 14 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23]],
             mask =
 [[False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

In this particular example you have issues with the `dtype` of `a`. If you add `a = a.astype(np.float)` before the creation of `b` it works just fine. There may be a faster way to create the indices then `np.where`.

Comment: You can just use `copyto` instead, which can use the mask directly, to avoid creating the `inds` array.

Comment: Or, you can do the whole thing with `where` itself, actually :P  `np.where(b.mask, c[...,None], b)`